# setting :style from method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a little issue with setting element's *width* by using *v-bind:style=...*

The deal is that properties for style are requried faster, than I can provide them (in *mounted*). Any idea how to force update after I will fill my array with *width*'s?

```
<template>
<div>
      <div class="headings ">
        <div class="t-cell head" v-for="(header, index) in headings"
             :style="'min-width:'+ getHeight(index) +'px'"
        >
          {{header}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-table text-inline" >
        <div class="t-cell head" v-for="(header, index) in headings" :ref="'head' + index">
          {{header}}
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        mounted: function(){
            this.getColumnWidths();
        },

        methods: {
          getHeight(index){
              return this.headerWidths[index];
          },
          getColumnWidths(){
            const _that=this;
            this.headings.forEach(function(element,index){
              _that.headerWidths[index] = _that.$refs['head'+index][0].clientWidth
            });
          },
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                headings: this.headersProp,
                headerWidths:[],

              }
        }

    }
</script>
```

It would be great if there would be some method to enforce update, as the width will probably change based on the content inserted.

### Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ydLzucbf/

Comment: Is your array a Vue-observable (e.g. a `data` or `computed` property of your view model)?

Comment: its just _headerWidths:[],_ in ``data`` . And it's starts empty, after I will render the table, I want to get the width of it's headers and that's what I'm doing with _getColumnWidths()_

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being bitten by the [array caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). Instead of assigning individual array elements (using `=`), use [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set):

```
getColumnWidths() {
  const _that = this;
  this.header.forEach(function(element, index) {
    _that.$set(_that.headerWidths, index, _that.$refs['head' + index][0].clientWidth)
  });
  console.log(this.headerWidths);
},
```

Comment: you are probably going to want to use `_that.$set(_that.headerWidths, index, _that.$refs['head' + index][0].clientWidth-32)` because you need to subtract the 32 pixels of border and padding